# How can I get Date field from the JSP page to repositoryFormHandler?

Tags: java, jsp, atg, atg-dynamo

I have created a JSP which has input field for date which accepts date like 1987-12-16

```
<dsp:input bean="RegisterFormHandler.dob" date="yyyy-MM-dd" size="25" type="text" required="true" />
```

and I am trying to set the value in RepositoryFormHandler

```
public void setDob(SimpleDateFormat dob) 
{
    this.dob = dob;
}
```

but set property is not calling the above function, I am not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: either way setDob() is not getting invoked to set the value. Ideally after submitting the formHandler it should call all the setters for the properties give on the form. It works for String/Integer field but not specifically for Date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to call `setDob(SimpleDateFormat dob)` where what you meant was `setDob(Date dob)`. You are not passing the format but the actual date.

That said, I've seen numerous examples in ATG when trying to pass the date in via a free-text field that ends up with unnecessary errors in the back end, even when you pass the 'date' format along. Most implementations, that work, will format the date with something like the jQuery `DatePicker` library and pass it to ATG as a `String` value. In your formhandler you then implement a validation method that will parse the `String` for being a valid date and return the appropriate exception. Your approach above is *fraught with danger*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are ways, but most of prefer as:

1. On JSP make a simple input box not desp:input
2. That inout box must have id or class, using that we set some dsp:input which is hidden in your jsp.
3. Write jQuery script which make the date as MM/DD/YYYY and set that hidden dsp:input value using jQuery.

`Jsp:-/*dsp:input */`

```
<dsp:getvalueof var="dateOfBirth" bean="ProfileFormHandler.value.dateOfBirth" />
```

/*simple input */

```
<input type="text" value="${dob}" maxlength="10" class="field text dob" id="accDOB" name="accDOB"></code>
```

/*jQuery */

```
    var accDOB = $('#accDOB').val();
    var d = accDOB.split("/");
    var dob = d[1]+'/'+d[0]+'/'+d[2];
    //convert the formate in mm/dd/yy
    $("#dob").val(dob);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: You might want to check how SO formats text as yours is a bit all over the place.

Comment: Surely using a `jQuery` library such as `DatePicker` is a better option? What if the user doesn't type in the full date or uses a '-' instead of a '/' to separate dd-MM-YY or if they correctly enter it as MM-dd-YY? What about binding to an event to populate the hidden input field.

Comment: I just give the idea, in form of code snippet. Yes there is binding of the event and validate the format accordingly. Thanks for reviewing.